# Searchview filtering gridview, and get switch case to the result instead of the first switch case

Tags: java, android, gridview

I have implemented a searchview to filter my gridview However I have also set up a switch case, which when you click the the different objects, it opens up a new activity. Example of what happens;

[This is the home screen, When you click on the first picture you get the corresponding activity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xHseg.jpg)

However, when you type something into the search bar it filters the results. I want to be able to click this picture and go to the proper corresponding activity. This is not the case and instead it goes to the first 'switch case' activity;

[Filtered results, Instead of showing the 3rd activity, its shows the first one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7pgrv.jpg)

So yeah, I understand why it is doing this, so I just need someone to put me down a path which will give me a solution.

Here is my code which handles the switch case of my gridview;

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    GridView gv = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView);
    gv = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView);
    sv = (SearchView) findViewById(R.id.searchView);


    final Adapter adapter = new Adapter(this, this.getChampions());
    gv.setAdapter(adapter);


    sv.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String arg0) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String query) {

            adapter.getFilter().filter(query);

            return false;
        }
    });

    gv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            switch( position )
            {
                case 0:  Intent newActivity = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Aatrox.class);
                    startActivity(newActivity);
                    break;

                case 1:  Intent newActivity2 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Ahri.class);
                    startActivity(newActivity2);
                    break;

                case 2:  Intent newActivity3 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Akali.class);
                    startActivity(newActivity3);
                    break;

            }
        }
    });

}

private ArrayList<Champions> getChampions() {
    ArrayList<Champions> champions = new ArrayList<Champions>();
    Champions p;

    for (int i = 0; i < Champions.length; i++) {
        p = new Champions(Champions[i], Champimgs[i]);
        champions.add(p);
    }
    return champions;
}
```

}

I have posted this trying to clarify my last post, which was flagged as a duplicate, to a question asking a completely different question, Thank you.

Comment: i think you cannot follow this approach because the number of items in gridview may increase or dicrease based on your search, at that time the position of items may not b constant (as you used 0,1,2), "Intent newActivity = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Aatrox.class)" this cannot be hardcoded in this case, you should use an unique property that will identify which item u have clicked, in simple words do not navigate your activity based on position because position may changed based on your search..

Comment: Did you understand wt i said pal? I have posted the answer follow that approach, for sure you will get solution , we are here for you to get solved that..Hurray:)

Comment: I do understand thank you, i tried your code below but once again i'm not doing something correct ;(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Remove your switch and Use Below Code**

```
if(ItemClicked.getName.equalIgnorecase("Aatrox")){
Intent newActivity = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Aatrox.class);
                startActivity(newActivity);

 }elseif(ItemClicked.getName.equalIgnorecase("Ahri")){
Intent newActivity2 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Ahri.class);
                startActivity(newActivity2);
}else if(ItemClicked.getName.equalIgnorecase("Akali")){
Intent newActivity3 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Akali.class);
                startActivity(newActivity3);
}
```

**Note:** Keep rest code as it is

Comment: Hello i have removed the switch and added your code like you said, however its throwing erros! - http://imgur.com/PdEAD1B

Comment: The thing is , this line of code is for your referrence "ItemClicked.getName.equalIgnorecase("Aatrox")" , do one thing could you post your xml i.e item xml which you have used in the adapter

Comment: "ItemClicked.getName" this you have to get from your adapter view, post your item xml i will guide you..

Comment: If you need anything else tell me :), thanks a heap for helping me

Comment: Not a prob bro..Love to help...check i have edited your code..http://pastebin.com/YSssQXEd

Comment: In this line of code  if(filterlist.get(i).getChampion().toUpperCase().contains(constraint)) - the i

Comment: sry check this ihave updated filter as well as adapter...http://pastebin.com/0fs9iUpi

Comment: update that line with this code, if(championsObject.getChampion().toUpperCase().contains(constraint)){
                      filters.add(championsObject);
                   }

Comment: Hello, replaced my code, i have the following errors - http://imgur.com/FYyjoDQ and http://imgur.com/NOGnDgV

Comment: pass the context from activity to ur adapter and save that conetxt in ur adapter and use savedContext.startActivity(newActivity);

Comment: context iis already there, jus use c.startActivity(); for all three

Comment: use c in place of MainActivity.this

Comment: :) Not a prob dude:)